# ItemControl background for child control

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml, wpf-controls, itemscontrol

In my WPF application, I have added ItemControl and I need to assign specific colors to the button' background in each row as shown in the screenshot. How can I achieve this?

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="MyItems" ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}" Background="Blue">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
             <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="{Binding ElementName=Grid, Path=ActualWidth}" Margin="0,0,0,20"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Margin="10,10,10,10">
                <Button Width="150" Height="120" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" CommandParameter="{Binding CategoryId}" >
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding CategoryName}" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Center" Margin="10"/>
                </Button>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

[Sample Screen]
[image]

Comment: Bind the Background of the StackPanel in the ItemTemplate to a Brush property in the item class.

Comment: @Clemens could you give me the sample code here

Comment: Please help me to solve this issue

Comment: Is the color of Button the color of the external container of ItemsControl? If not, do you have any color requirements for buttons?